# Create database using SSMS GUI fails for Azure SQL Managed Instance

Tags: sql-server, azure, virtual-machine, ssms, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have spun up a new instance of Azure SQL Managed Instance which appears to be working. I have then created a Jumpbox virtual machine, as per the docs, to manage various components of the virtual network including the managed SQL instance.

I can connect to the Azure SQL Managed Instance (using the admin credentials I specified when spinning the service up) via SSMS on the Jumpbox but when I attempt to create a new database I get the exception below.

[image]

```
===================================

Create failed for Database 'ODP'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

------------------------------
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=14.0.17289.0+((SSMS_Rel_17_4).181117-0805)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Create+Database&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.CreateImpl()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.CreateDatabaseData.DatabasePrototype.ApplyChanges(Control marshallingControl)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.CreateDatabase.DoPreProcessExecution(RunType runType, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.DoPreProcessExecutionAndRunViews(RunType runType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.ExecuteForSql(PreProcessExecutionInfo executionInfo, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.IExecutionAwareSqlControlCollection.PreProcessExecution(PreProcessExecutionInfo executionInfo, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.ViewSwitcherControlsManager.RunNow(RunType runType, Object sender)
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is failing? I am logged into the instance using the admin credentials and the Jumpbox using the admin credentials. I have also tried running SSMS as admin in Windows with the same issue.

The error suggests there may be a missing dependancy as part of the installation of SSMS but I have not idea what that might be.

**EDIT:**

From looking around I was wondering if this can only be completed from a Powershell or Bash script. Anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you check your version of SSMS? Please use SSMS 18+ (preview) because this might be some issue in older version of the SSMS.

Comment: Jovan, I am using v17.9.1. I will try to update and retest. This was installed using the script reference on the Azure SQL Managed Instance getting started page so I would suggest that it is updated.

Answer (score 0):

OK,

Looks like this may not be supported SSMS GUI. I just tried to create a new DB via a T-SQL command and it worked. Looks like it's also possible via Bash and Powershell scripts as described in the below links.

[Managed API reference for Azure SQL Database Managed Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-create-manage)

[CREATE DATABASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-mi-current)

New technology I suppose...

Anyone else have experience with this?